# how to delete video

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

i can upload video to my facebook page via graph api. and i cant delete this video.

i trying this but not work (php sdk)

```
$facebook->api("/VIDEO_ID", "DELETE", array('access_token' => 'ACCESS_TOKEN'));
```

this request responsing bellow error

```
GraphMethodException: Unsupported delete request.
```

but i can deleting this way any feed post

i have `manage_pages` permission.

im sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported to delete videos via the API