# Is it possible to delete Facebook Video via Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

However if I try to send a `DELETE` to `{video-id}` I get `Unsupported delete request`, even when `curl`ing.

Related question from 2011 says it can't be deleted but docs says that it CAN be deleted.

`{"error":{"message":"Unsupported delete request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100}}`

docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video#deleting

related SO question: [how to delete video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507599/how-to-delete-video)

Comment: And it was your app that published this video in the first place?

Comment: @CBroe yes. Just uploaded it. I have the ID for the video and the same token, with publish_stream, publish_actions and user_videos permission.

Comment: I created brand new app with default setting and tested with test users. I tested with 3 scenarios: post and remove video with user access token, post with user access token and remove it with app token, and posting and removing with app token. (user access token is required so the later 2 scenarios should be invalid, but I just wnated to make sure.) I ended up reproducing the same problem as yours.
The code is here: https://gist.github.com/oklahomer/11391286

Comment: I reported a bug https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1595003230723916/

Comment: @Oklahomer, just +1 your issue at Facebook. Normally they take days/months to respond those bug reports. Sad... Hope someone has the correct endpoint to delete videos.

Sometimes facebook documentation is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently I got a [reply from Facebook Developer Center](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1595003230723916/).

Although the document said we can delete the video in the way you described, it wasn't implemented. And they are not going to implement it for now.
The below capture is the document they used to have.
[image]
Now this part is gone.

They said...

> This issue/feature will not be worked on right now, sorry about that. 
>   Once we decide to launch this feature, we will update the documentation to reflect it.